# Pop values off Stack<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, stack

So I'm trying to create a backtracking recursive algorithm for maze generation using the stack to store the coordinates of the last spot entered in an array of ints [x,y]. When I try to store the results of .Pop off the stack, it sets my variable for the first popped value but not off of the next.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        Stack<int[]> myStack = new Stack<int[]>();

        int[] pusher = new int[] {1,2};
        myStack.Push(pusher);

        pusher[0] = 3;
        pusher[1] = 4;
        myStack.Push(pusher);

        while(myStack.Count > 0){
            int[] test = myStack.Pop();
            for(int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++){
                Console.WriteLine(test[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Wanted result would be that the console displays 3,4,1,2. Instead I'm getting back 3,4,3,4.

Comment: You're reusing the same array instance so you're in fact pushing the same array onto the stack twice. When you store 3 and 4 into the array you overwrite the 1 and 2 already there. `Push` does not make a copy of the array contents, only of the array reference, therefore you push the same array twice. If you want to push a copy, use `myStack.Push(pusher.ToArray());`

Comment: i would define a class for the stored objects rather that an array. Since the object you push are the coordinates of a point you just need an X and Y value.; not an open-ended array of ints. If I am reading your question correctly

Comment: Thank you, @LasseVågsætherKarlsen! I understand that.

Comment: Standard failure to understand reference types. See marked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating one array - `pusher`. You are then simply replacing the numbers 1 and 2 at the indexes 0 and 1 of this array respectively.

If you create another array and add 3 and 4 to this one, you will get the expected results:

```
Stack<int[]> myStack = new Stack<int[]>();

int[] pusher = new int[] { 1, 2 };
myStack.Push(pusher);

int[] second = new int[2];
second[0] = 3;
second[1] = 4;
myStack.Push(second);

while (myStack.Count > 0)
{
    int[] test = myStack.Pop();
    for (int i = 0; i<test.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would tentatively be a solution, but the problem is in the actual situation I'm not working with only 2 coordinates. I'm working with hundreds....

Comment: What's your point? You still cannot overwrite the values and expect to be able to pop them...

Comment: My point is that it's not practical to create hundreds of variables. Look up to the comments on my question. Lasse seems to have answered correctly.

Comment: ToArray() creates another array just as much as int[] second = new int[2] do in my example so I don't really see your point. And it must be must more "practical" not to overwrite the values you wish to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered by Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen in comments on question. Moving to answer.:

You're reusing the same array instance so you're in fact pushing the same array onto the stack twice. When you store 3 and 4 into the array you overwrite the 1 and 2 already there. Push does not make a copy of the array contents, only of the array reference, therefore you push the same array twice. If you want to push a copy, use myStack.Push(pusher.ToArray()); – Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen 4 hours ago